# Atom (python) - paste multiple lines into command prompt

Tags: python, atom-editor, copy-paste

I'm used to writing python code in **Atom** and copy-paste into window command prompt to test and see immediate output. (let's not talk about if this is an efficient way or not here :) It usually allowed me to copy and paste multiple lines at once, but today, all of a sudden, command prompt does not recognize multiple lines.

For example, for the same code

```
list = []
n = [1,2,3]
for i in n:
    list.append(i)
```

Command prompt used to read my copy-pasting as something like (I don't recall how it exactly looks)

```
>>> list = []
>>> n = [1,2,3]
>>> for i in n:
...    list.append(i)
```

But now it read:

```
>>> list = [] n = [1,2,3] for i in n:    list.append(i)
```

I don't think the problem is with command prompt because when I copy from my question on StackOverlow, it reads perfectly. I suppose this is something with Atom, but I have no idea what changed/happened.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Has the configuration of newlines changes in atom?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hi thanks for your response! I don't recall changing any configurations. Just in case, where is the configuration of newlines you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (inspired by this https://discuss.atom.io/t/make-lf-the-default-newline-format/53354):

Settings -> Packages -> Line Ending Selector -> change the “Default line ending” setting to “CRLF”.

This can also be changed here: [image]